# pybind11, cmake: how to install files?

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pybind11

I'm interfacing a C++ library with the ever more popular [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) to get native Python bindings; configuration is via `CMake`.

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(foo)

FILE(GLOB foo_SRCS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp")

FIND_PACKAGE(pybind11 REQUIRED)
pybind11_add_module(mylib ${foo_SRCS})
```

This doesn't seem to register installation rules, however. Hence, while everything works as expected in the build tree, `make install` doesn't do anything.

What needs to be added to get the installation in order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just the usual CMake install commands:

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)

install(TARGETS mylib
  COMPONENT python
  RUNTIME DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}"
  LIBRARY DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}"
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}")
```

for Unix. You can manually make up the destination directories for other platforms. The "COMPONENT" part is optional, but just neater for different types of installers.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the created library to the `python<version>/site-packages` directory

```
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development REQUIRED)
...
install(TARGETS mylib
        COMPONENT python
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "lib/python${Python3_VERSION_MAJOR}.${Python3_VERSION_MINOR}/site-packages"
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "lib"
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "bin")
```

That way the python interpreter finds the library without additional manipulation of `PYTHONPATH`

The variables `Python3_VERSION_MAJOR` and `Python3_VERSION_MINOR` are provided by the `find_package' instruction