# How to create a Python package from a PyBind11 module created with CMake

Tags: python, python-packaging, pybind11

I have a C++ code using Cmake & make for the building part.
I also have python bindings to this code thanks to PyBind11.

I use `pybind11_add_module` inside CMakeLists.txt and now when I build (`cmake -Bbuild && cd build && make`) it creates a python_module.so in the build directory.

I can move it manually elsewhere, and if the module is in the same folder I can use it in python scripts.

Now I'd like to "package" this module and I don't know how. My goal would be to be able to `pip install python_package_from_module` to use it anywhere without the need to manually move/duplicate the python_module.so file. (Edit/Note : for now I don't want to publish my package on PiPy, just to be able to pip install locally the package)

Do you know how to do that ? I don't have a lot of knowledge about packaging, I've only done it once with a pyproject.toml and a setup.cfg.

The only examples I found use setup.py and are way more complicated. For example I must admit that I really don't understand how does this [Pybind11 Cmake Example](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example) work.

Comment: I answer my own question, two months later, but I found the best example of what I wanted to do on this [cookiecutter](https://github.com/scikit-hep/cookie/) with scikit-build  and PyBind11.  [scikit-build](https://scikit-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) seems really promising to make the packaging of binary extensions an easier task.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to import your module without having to move the .so file manually.

Running `python3 setup.py install` should both compile your module via cmake and do the necessary linking. After that you should be able to import your module as usual.

Comment: I don't have a setup.py. I have a CMakeLists.txt creating a .so file ; the link I gave show a setup.py but then again I don't understand a line of it and how to adapt it to my project and I don't really find explanations online

Comment: You can just copy the setup.py from that github project and change the setup() function at the end with information about your module. That script just does some dependency/platform checking and then runs the cmake commands. From what I understand using setup.py is the correct way of installing your module and is necessary if you want to upload your module to pypi for example.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76667253/120182870),
I installed the created library to the `python<version>/site-packages` directory:

```
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development REQUIRED)

...

pybind11_add_module( mylib MODULE
            mylib.cxx
            )

...

install(TARGETS mylib
        COMPONENT python
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "lib/python${Python3_VERSION_MAJOR}.${Python3_VERSION_MINOR}/site-packages"
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "lib"
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "bin")
```

That way the python interpreter finds the library without additional manipulation of PYTHONPATH

The variables Python3_VERSION_MAJOR and Python3_VERSION_MINOR are provided by the `find_package' instruction

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34676615)